# When aligning an equation at multiple places, how to make the elements centered?

Tags: math-mode, alignat

I'm trying to typeset a composition of maps. A bit searching over this site suggests that `alignat` is the right tool, and I managed to write this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
    \iota \colon X &\to     X \times [0,1] &\to&     C(X)    \\
                 x &\mapsto (x,0)          &\mapsto& [(x,0)] .
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

The question is that, how should one make the elements between the arrows centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve your formatting objective with an `alignat*` environment, at least not all that easily. I suggest you employ an `array` environment instead.

[image]

Note that I took the `\iota\colon` part out of the `array` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,xcolor}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary and relational operators
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{\texttt{alignat*}}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \iota \colon X &\to     X \times [0,1] &{}\to{}    & C(X)    \\
                 x &\mapsto (x,0)          &{}\mapsto{}& [(x,0)] .
\end{alignat*}

\textcolor{red}{\texttt{array}}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\iota\colon
\begin{array}[t]{rCcCl}
                 X &\to    & X \times [0,1] &\to    & C(X)    \\[0.33ex]
                 x &\mapsto& (x,0)          &\mapsto& [(x,0)] .
\end{array}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask what does `>{{}}c<{{}}` mean?

Comment: @Jinwen - It defines the `C` column type as being of type `c` ("centered"), except that the column contents will be prefixed and affixed by `{}`. Thus, say, `\to` becomes `{}\to{}`, etc. This, in turn, assures that TeX will insert the right amount of padding (aka horizontal whitespace) around the arrow. Observe that in your screenshot, there's no padding around the arrows on the RHS -- not quite right. I fixed this issue in "my" `alignat*` environment by replacing `\to` and `\mapsto` with `{}\to{}` and `{}\mapsto{}`, respectively. The `array`-based solution automates this fix.